# z-index stacking elements outside of what is specified

Tags: html, css, z-index

I used `z-index` to stack a few input boxes and some text on top of an image which worked how I wanted it to. As I continued on and started the next section of my page it, it moved the next section up behind the image that is using `z-index`. How do I get my next section to follow the normal flow of the page under the image and not stacked behind it?

Comment: example code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image needs to have `position: relative` (not `absolute`) - that way it will remain part of the document flow.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that issue, now my input boxes are no longer on top of the image, what do I do now?

Comment: Well, I suppose your input boxes have `position: absolute`. Use higher `z-index` values on them to move them to the foreground.

Comment: and if your image is not inside a DIV, apply `display: block` to it